# sql query for re-ordering data based on sort order sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

```
tablename =  zones

  ID     sort_order  area_name
======== =========   =========
  1        1          aaaa
  3        2          bbbb
  5        3          cccc
  7        4          dddd
  8        5          eeeee
```

i need to add a new area_name

eg: ffff in place of sort_order = 3.

and re-arrange the remaining areas sort_orders accordingly as shown below

```
  ID     sort_order  area_name
======== =========   =========
  1        1          aaaa
  3        2          bbbb
  9        3          ffff
  5        4          cccc
  7        5          dddd
  8        6          eeeee
```

need sql query for this

Comment: Update 'cccc' with 'ffff' and add new row with 'eeee'. That's the logic. Now you need is one update query and one Insert query. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UPDATE` and `INSERT`. I'm assuming that `ID` is auto-generated. The `UPDATE` makes room for the new record in the `sort_order` sequence and then you can easily insert.

```
 UPDATE zones
 SET sort_order = sort_order + 1
 WHERE sort_order >= 3

 INSERT INTO zones(sort_order , area_name) 
 VALUES (3, 'ffff')
```

However, if the `zones` table is heavily inserted then you will experience a lot of blocking wait.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 queries to do that.. First of all you update the `sort_orders` of the existing entries and insert the new entry afterwards:

```
UPDATE zones SET sort_order=sort_order + 1 WHERE sort_order >= 3;
INSERT INTO zones VALUES (NULL, 3, 'ffff')
```